# Authorization for Google openbidder source code repository

Tags: google-api, google-ad-manager

I am a masters student working on my academic project. I would like to checkout goodle open bidder source code repository. So filled out the form requesting for the authorization to the source code but havent received a response from google whether my request has been approved or disapproved.

Could anyone please help me understand how the authorization process works.

Comment: The [Open Bidder forum](https://developers.google.com/ad-exchange/rtb/open-bidder/community/) would be a better place to ask your question.

Comment: @abraham thank you. I posted the question in the forum and got the information. Looks like Google open-bidder is only available for those who are using google adexhange and google compute engine.